# Meaning and usage of "just so you know"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Please explain me the meaning of **"just so you know"** and give some examples of  using this phrase.

What is the difference between ***"just so you know"*** and ***"for your information"?***

Answer (score 1):

**Just so you know meaning**

> A phrase tacked on to the end of a statement to imply that the
>   information being given is simply a courtesy, when in reality there
>   are specific expectations of you now that you have this information.

**Usage**

> What Danielle says to guy she's been seeing: Oh, hey I decativated my
>   profile on the dating website, just so you know.

What Danielle REALLY means: You better take your dang profile off the dating website too....NOW!!!!

[Source](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=just%20so%20you%20know)

PS: There's this thing called Google where you can type in a commonly used phrase and get its meaning and its usage on the very first result, ***just so you know***.